# Apache, mod_wsgi, Django - strange 500 errors

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a Django site which works well most of the time, memory usage is stable and I wouldn't have to worry if not some strange problems, which were occasional until yesterday and cause site to go down for the whole last night.

Configuration:

- Debian Lenny
- Apache 2.2 prefork
- mod_wsgi 2.5
- Python 2.5.2
- Django 1.2.5

Tracebacks I get:

```
[error] mod_wsgi (pid=7390): Exception occurred within sys.exitfunc().
[error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
[error]     func(*targs, **kargs)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1354, in shutdown
[error]     h.flush()
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 731, in flush
[error]     self.stream.flush()
[error] IOError: sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi
```

The above one is often generated when I restart Apache or touch .wsgi file, so I'm not concerned about it that much. The following ones are more interesting:

```
[error] [client ..] mod_wsgi (pid=8184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '.../django.wsgi'.
[error] [client ..] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error] [client ..] File ".../django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 248, in __call__
[error] [client ..]   response = self.get_response(request)
[error] [client ..] File ".../django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
[error] [client ..]   receivers = signals.got_request_exception.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request)
[error] [client ..] File "...django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
[error] [client ..]   response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
[error] [client ..] File "...django/db/transaction.py", line 299, in _commit_on_success
[error] [client ..]   res = func(*args, **kw)
[error] [client ..] File ".../apps/utils/middleware.py", line 28, in exception_handler
[error] [client ..]   'url': request.get_full_path()
[error] [client ..] File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1015, in error
[error] [client ..]   apply(self._log, (ERROR, msg, args), kwargs)
[error] [client ..] File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1101, in _log
[error] [client ..]   self.handle(record)
[error] [client ..] File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1111, in handle
[error] [client ..]   self.callHandlers(record)
[error] [client ..] File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1148, in callHandlers
[error] [client ..]   hdlr.handle(record)
[error] [client ..] File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/__init__.py", line 655, in handle
[error] [client ..]   self.emit(record)
[error] [client ..] File "../apps/py26_logging/handlers.py", line 394, in emit
[error] [client ..]   self.stream.flush()
[error] [client ..] ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

One word of explanation: because I use logrotate for log rotation, I "backported" logging.WatchedFileHandler from Python 2.6 to the project, which is placed in `apps/py26_logging/handlers.py`, but my guess is that it's not the WatchedFileHandler that causes this and that it only suffers from the more general problem - because for 95% of time it works perfectly.

Anyway, Apache restart cures the problem immediately (until next time of course).

ServerDensity, which I use for server monitoring, shows a stable memory usage (flat line) with at least 500mb of free memory at any time, number of processes is also stable and in general nothing unusual happens in stats when my app goes crazy.

I tried reproducing the problem with ApacheBench, but I didn't manage to fail any single request unless I used 100 simultaneous ones:

Concurrency Level:      100
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        1
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 1, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      1

I don't have to mention that this was way beyond the usual load and ServerDensity stats spiked up a lot.

Does someone of you see a familiar pattern here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can just comment on the `IOError: sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi` error. Something in your Django-App writes stuff to `sys.stdout` which is restricted by mod_wsgi. Usually no output ever happens to `sys.stdout` in a WSGI application. You could use `WSGIRestrictStdout Off` in your global Apache configuration (not vhost) as a band-aid. For a permanent and clean solution, get rid of any `print` or whatever writes to `sys.stdout`. For more details look at the [mod_wsgi documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out some time ago but I don't have any writes to `stdout` anyway. I thought that maybe Python or mod_wsgi writes there something when daemon is terminated, but it might be an interaction with development server running on the same Apache instance, in different WSGI daemon but within the same  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}. I might be completely wrong here, though.

Comment: You may not have explicit 'print' statements, but the traceback above indicates that the logging module is using stdout and is attempting to flush it on shutdown. Upgrade to mod_wsgi 3.X and stop using 2.X and the problem will go away. The restriction was lifted in 3.0 because people didn't want to address why their code was using stdin/stdout even though doing so means you don't have a portable WSGI application. See 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/04/wsgi-and-printing-to-standard-output.html'.

Comment: @Graham: Thanks, I already read that blog entry - I made sure that there's no stdout handler in my logging configuration but the problem didn't go away. Out of sudden it went away a few hours ago, when I redirected `sys.stdout` to `sys.stderr`, but this is more a hack than a solution - I still don't understand what was (and is) wrong. Here is next question on my way of understanding the root cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021424/mod-wsgi-daemon-mode-wsgiapplicationgroup-and-python-interpreter-separation

Comment: The traceback shows 'self.stream.flush()'. The value of 'self.stream' must be 'sys.stdout' somehow.

Comment: You are probably right, I was misled by the other strange tracebacks. I'll investigate this more thorough because there should be no `sys.stdout`

Comment: @Graham: You had been right, but the problem was more tricky than simple flush of `sys.stdout` - `logging` module changed a lot in Python 2.6 and my backported `WatchedFileHandler` was causing subtle errors. I'm still not sure where did `stdout` creep out from, but backporting whole `logging` module from Python 2.6 solved that problem. Also, I had a subtle sys.path problem that caused `logging` to be imported twice. Summarizing, I learned once again that there is no magic in programming and if Google doesn't know the answer to my problem directly, then I better double-check it.